# inserting multiple checkbox value from PHP to MYSql

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have this code below that needs to insert "ticked" Checkbox into MySQL.

I have everything setup and it is connecting to the database, it is inserting a new column on the table but there is no text in the column and just blank space

Heres the code that I HAVE (btw I am using NETBEANS as my IDE)

PHP QUERY

```
if(!empty(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'items')))
 {
     foreach(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'items') as $value )
     {
         $insert= mysql_query("INSERT INTO items_bought('Items_Description') VALUES ('$value')");
           if ($insert)
              {
                echo"<script>alert('submitted');</script>"
              }
          else
              {
                echo"<script>alert('Not Submitted');"
              }
     }
 }
```

HTML form

```
<input type="checkbox" name="items[]" value="coinpurse">coinpurse
<input type="checkbox" name="items[]" value="jacket">jacket
<input type="checkbox" name="items[]" value="tumbler">tumbler
<button type ="submit" name="submit" value="send to database"> SEND TO DATABASE </button>
```

Comment: use serialize to insert array values into the database like this serialize($_POST['items']);

Comment: apparently netbeans is suggesting that I use filter_input instead of $_POST something about "do not use global....."

Comment: What happens when you put var_dump(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'items')) at the top of the code and die; ?